# Switching to a new tab/window which is having xml-style-view instead of web-view in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a scenario wherein when I click a button on a page, it gets redirected to a new page in a separate tab. Now the new page is not a regular page, And when I use normal switchTo().window() operations, it does not work saying "Web view not found, target window closed.

How should I handle this scenario in selenium

A screenshot of the result xml-viewer-style page

[image: e]

Comment: Does this help? - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44461795/7352883

Answer (score 0):

What is the resultant pages complete path? Does it end with XML? And why do you want that page? I believe that page is an XML file opening in a new tab. If you have stuff to retrieve from that page, you need to first download it as an XML file. Then use a parser to retrieve the data from it.

You can use DOM to parse an XML file like so:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(response));
Document doc = builder.parse(is);

NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
Node namedItem = nList.item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("uid");
System.out.println(namedItem.getNodeValue());
```

Now before you even can do that, you have to get that file to your local system.

You can do it using a dummy argument in the href for your file like so

```
<a href="http://link/to/file.xml?dummy=dummy" download>Download Now</a>
```

Comment: The thing is when I click on  a submit button, that xml page gets opened with the the results in xml view. The structure is same as in the screenshot. The URL does not end with the .xml

Comment: There are ways to make your browser auto download on click. This is possible in Firefox but not in Chrome. If you are using FirefoxDriver, let me know. It can be configured to auto download on click.